# When passing an object as an argument to a method, string properties are populated, but integers are null

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I'm not sure WCF being involved is significant or not.

I have a class and method exposed to a client asp.net app. The class looks like

```
<DataContract()> _
Public Class Class1
  Private v_string As String
  Private v_integer As Integer

  Public Sub New()
      v_string = ""
      v_integer = -1
  End Sub

  <DataMember()> _
  Public Property P_String() As String
    Get
        Return v_string
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
       v_string = value
    End Set
  End Property

  <DataMember()> _
  Public Property P_Integer() As Integer
    Get
        Return v_integer
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
       v_integer = value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

The method is declared as

```
<OperationContract()> _
Function GetStuff(ByVal bar As Class1) As String
```

In the client code I create an instance of Class1 and set the values for v_string and v_integer, but using Wireshark to look at the xml being sent to the server only a value for v_string is being sent as part of Class1.  I'm guessing this is because it considers the value of v_integer to be null/not set.  Here is an example of the client code.

```
Dim MyService as New Service1.ServiceClient
Dim test as New Service1.Class1
test.P_integer = 1
test.P_string = "hello"
Dim result as String = MyService.GetStuff(test)
```

I'm guessing this is a problem with how different types are passed/used since Integer is a intergral type and String is a class, but can't seem to work out what to do to fix the problem.

Comment: thanks marc_s, I fixed.  it was a typo in my sanitized code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine found that everthing works properly we change the decorations for the data members from:

```
<DataMember()>_
Public Property P_Integer() As Integer
...
End Property
```

To:

```
<DataMember(IsRequired:=True)> _
Public Property P_Integer() As Integer
...
End Property
```

for all value types.  Class types such as string work fine without this.

Answer (score 2):

WCF will only ever transmit data - you **cannot** expose a "method" via WCF.

WCF is a **serialized messaging** system - only serialized data travels between client and server - there is **no other connection** (no "remote object" or something like that) going on.

But both `string` and `int` should be handled no problem....

Maybe you are stumbling over this behavior?? I don't fully understand where your problem is, too - what are you expecting, and what are you seeing instead?? What does your service method actually do in its implementation??

**Update:** when I do the same thing as you have, and then use [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to see what's happening, this is the request going into the service:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://localhost:8433/Services/GetStuff</To>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IGetStuffService/GetStuff</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetStuff xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
       <data xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/wcf_test" 
             xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
           <a:P_Integer>5</a:P_Integer>
           <a:P_String>Where to go for holidays...</a:P_String>
       </data>
    </GetStuff>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

So what is it you're not seeing that should be there??..... I clearly see both the integer and the string value in that SOAP message - as expected.

Could it be you're not seeing your value of `1` because that's hidden away in the byte stream somewhere?? Try specifying some other value, like `4711067` or something - that won't get lost in your message....

To enable WCF tracing, put these two sections into your `web.config` or `app.config` of your WCF service:

```
<system.diagnostics>
   <sources>
       <source name="UserTraceSource" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing" >
          <listeners>
              <add name="xml"
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="C:\logs\UserTraces.svclog" />
          </listeners>
       </source>
   </sources>
   <trace autoflush="true" /> 
</system.diagnostics>
```

(make sure the `C:\logs` directory exists before hand!!), and

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging maxMessagesToLog="30000"
                logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
                logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false" 
                logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true">
            <filters>
               <clear/>
            </filters>
         </messageLogging>
     </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Now you'll get `*.svclog` files in `C:\logs` - open Windows Explorer, double-click on them, and you should be taken into the [WCF Trace Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) for analysis.

Comment: I'm expecting to see XML being sent back with values for the String and the Integer contained in the class. I only see values for the String

Comment: @Leroy: can you try to enable WCF tracing on your service side, and see what you get??

Comment: @marc_s looking into that now.

Comment: For some reason when I setup tracing I see plenty of info, but I can't find the actual message.  When grab the packets off the wire that's were I see that the integer is not being passed.  In your trace it looks like P_Integer and P_String are just parameters to GetStuff.  In my case they are properties of an object.  Passing them both just as parameters works fine for me as well.

Comment: @Leroy: oh no, I have a <data> structure, which is exactly what your class looks like (class with two properties). I'm **not** passing them as separate parameters!

Comment: @Leroy: in my case, I get about 15 messages or so for a single method call - typically, the second but last is the request coming in from the client, and the very last is the response going back to the client.

Comment: @marc_s, would it be possible for you to stick your sample project somewhere for me to grab, so I can look for differences?

Comment: @marc_s I see activities in the trace viewer, but not messages, must have something setup wrong in the diagnostics, I tried copying what you had and it didn't log anything, I then just used the WCF Configurator to setup tracing.

Comment: I have the message trace working.  Mine looks the same as marc_s, but missing the P_Integer parameter.  It looks like the client is not sending it I don't know why.  Even if I leave the P_String parameter null it still gets passed with a value of null.  The integer just isn't getting passed.

Comment: @Leroy: OK, but then there **Must** be something different about your code.... I uploaded my sample (C#) to:  [hhtp://www.bluenose.ch/Stack/WCFTestData_Sample.zip]   go grab it and have a look....

Comment: @marc_s, thanks for the code.  I'm stumped and will keep working, I see no difference between our code other than languauge choice.  The only other difference is how/where the service is hosted, but that shouldn't matter at all.

Answer (score 1):

A client of ours is having the same problem and we have not found a fix, the encapsulated a WCF service in a vb.net 4.0 dll and then from thier exe they showed me from thier machine they are passing strings and integers, with a packet sniffer on my server, the only soap xml tags i see are the string tags.

I have written a client in c# 4.0 and it works fine, even from thier machine.

Michael Evanchik

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite make sense to me:

```
<DataMember()> _
  Public Property P_Integer() As Integer
    Get
        Return v_integer
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
       v_string = value
    End Set
  End Property
```

Shouldn't that Set function be:

```
v_integer = value
```